# How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

It seems rather odd that I can't figure how to do this in mustache. Is it supported?

This is my sad attempt at trying:

```
    {{#author}}
      {{#avatar}}
        <img src="{{avatar}}"/>
      {{/avatar}}
      {{#!avatar}}
        <img src="/images/default_avatar.png" height="75" width="75" />
      {{/avatar}}
    {{/author}}
```

This obviously isn't right, but the documentation doesn't mention anything like this. The word "else" isn't even mentioned :(

Also, why is mustache designed this way? Is this sort of thing considered bad? Is it trying to force me to set the default value in the model itself? What about the cases where that isn't possible?

Comment: "why is mustache designed this way?" I'm not too sure, but I think the idea is that a templating language should be just that: a language for writing templates, i.e. things that look like the output they produce, just with holes where the variable bits go. Putting logic in the template language makes the templates more complicated, and when you've already got a programming language to handle the logic bits, why bother?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Logic-less" really means "non-arbitrary code," I think. It's just as bad to put true view logic in code as it is to put non-view logic in a template. Mustache tries to provide a bare minimum logic to accomplish that.

Comment: Or use [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) instead of mustache. Being able to write, e.g. `{{#each items}}{{#unless @first}}Output comma before 2nd, 3rd, 4th...{{/unless}}{{/each}}` is more readable, much cleaner, and is still presentation. "Logic-less" is a guideline, it doesn't have to be a straitjacket.

Comment: Maybe it's not a versatile-enough templating engine when an OP says "this is my sad attempt [...] this obviously isn't right" ...and then the accepted answer is a copy-paste of that code :). No judgment on OP or answer; just on `mustache`

Comment: if you're on PHP, try `sm-mustache`, i've implemented `|` else block to cut those extra declarations..

Answer (score 582, accepted):

This is how you do if/else in Mustache (perfectly supported):

```
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
{{^repo}}
  No repos :(
{{/repo}}
```

Or in your case:

```
{{#author}}
  {{#avatar}}
    <img src="{{avatar}}"/>
  {{/avatar}}
  {{^avatar}}
    <img src="/images/default_avatar.png" height="75" width="75" />
  {{/avatar}}
{{/author}}
```

Look for inverted sections in the docs: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#inverted-sections

Comment: The mustache docs are hilarious. "We call it "logic-less" because there are no if statements, else clauses, or for loops."

Yeeeeaaaaaa....

Comment: @boxed, technically you're right, the inverted section is a logical statement, as it checks the tag value. But, I think the nuance here is that both statements have to be explicitly evaluated, rather than a single if/else. Basically, mustache forces the structure `if (condition){ //do something}` followed by a `if (!condition){//do something else}`. Also, the amount of logic that one can perform in logic extremely reduced compared to a logic-based language. Existence or  non-existence are the only checks, i.e. you can't check if the value of a tag equals 5 and then fall into that tag's code.

Comment: @MandM yea... so it has logic but it just can't do anything useful :P

Comment: It just keeps you way from messing with if else logic . Having a lot of nested if/else inside another if/else is a sign of misdesign

Comment: @boxed you can do for loop with moustache.js (at least ngFor-ish loop)

Comment: basically I need something like this
 <li class="{{^self.link"}}noLink{{^self.link"}} {{^self.detail"}}noDetail{{^self.detail}}">
means if some object available adding a class name
but how can I do this with mustache ?

Comment: Mustache is logic-less because indeed it forces you to put business logic outside of the view, which is a good thing. If you are wondering how to do an if/else in a view you're most likely doing it wrong, and should move that logic to the controller. Refactoring in that way keeps the views much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 59):

This is something you solve in the "controller", which is the point of logicless templating.

```
// some function that retreived data through ajax
function( view ){

   if ( !view.avatar ) {
      // DEFAULTS can be a global settings object you define elsewhere
      // so that you don't have to maintain these values all over the place
      // in your code.
      view.avatar = DEFAULTS.AVATAR;
   }

   // do template stuff here

}
```

This is actually a LOT better then maintaining image url's or other media that might or might not change in your templates, but takes some getting used to. The point is to unlearn template tunnel vision, an avatar img url is bound to be used in other templates, are you going to maintain that url on X templates or a single DEFAULTS settings object? ;)

Another option is to do the following:

```
// augment view
view.hasAvatar = !!view.avatar;
view.noAvatar = !view.avatar;
```

And in the template:

```
{{#hasAvatar}}
    SHOW AVATAR
{{/hasAvatar}}
{{#noAvatar}}
    SHOW DEFAULT
{{/noAvatar}}
```

But that's going against the whole meaning of logicless templating. If that's what you want to do, you want logical templating and you should not use Mustache, though do give it yourself a fair chance of learning this concept ;)

Comment: Thanks. That's a great response! It actually helped me with other structural aspects too about "when to do stuff" in the structure of the javascript code.

Comment: {{/#hasAvatar}} and {{/#noAvatar}} should be {{/hasAvatar}} and {{/noAvatar}} in this answer.

Answer (score 18):

Your *else* statement should look like this (note the `^`):

```
{{^avatar}}
 ...
{{/avatar}}
```

In mustache this is called 'Inverted sections'.

Comment: note that you don't need both # and ^, it's just ^ for 'not' case

Comment: That does not work in the latest version. Zappan is correct, you only need the ^

Answer (score 15):

Note, you can use `{{.}}` to render the current context item.

```
{{#avatar}}{{.}}{{/avatar}}

{{^avatar}}missing{{/avatar}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper in the view. However, the conditional logic is somewhat limited. Moxy-Stencil (https://github.com/dcmox/moxyscript-stencil) seems to address this with "parameterized" helpers, eg:

```
{{isActive param}}
```

and in the view:

```
view.isActive = function (path: string){ return path === this.path ? "class='active'" : '' }
```