# How to handle an IF STATEMENT in a Mustache template?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I'm using mustache. I'm generating a list of notifications. A notification JSON object looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1364,
    "read": true,
    "author_id": 30,
    "author_name": "Mr A",
    "author_photo": "image.jpg",
    "story": "wants to connect",
    "notified_type": "Friendship",
    "action": "create"
  }
]
```

With mustache, how can I do a if statement or case statement based on the `notified_type` & `action`...

If `notified_type == "Friendship"` render ......

If `notified_type == "Other && action == "invite"` render.....

How does that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Mustache templates are, by design, very simple; the [homepage](http://mustache.github.com/) even says:

> Logic-less templates.

So the general approach is to do your logic in JavaScript and set a bunch of flags:

```
if(notified_type == "Friendship")
    data.type_friendship = true;
else if(notified_type == "Other" && action == "invite")
    data.type_other_invite = true;
//...
```

and then in your template:

```
{{#type_friendship}}
    friendship...
{{/type_friendship}}
{{#type_other_invite}}
    invite...
{{/type_other_invite}}
```

If you want some more advanced functionality but want to maintain most of Mustache's simplicity, you could look at [Handlebars](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/):

> Handlebars provides the power necessary to let you build semantic templates effectively with no frustration.
>
> Mustache templates are compatible with Handlebars, so you can take a Mustache template, import it into Handlebars, and start taking advantage of the extra Handlebars features.

Comment: this answer is not wrong, but the correct/better answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27680634/918858)

Answer (score 148):

Just took a look over the mustache docs and they support "inverted sections" in which they state

> they (inverted sections) will be rendered if the key doesn't exist, is false, or is an empty list

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Inverted-Sections

```
{{#value}}
  value is true
{{/value}}
{{^value}}
  value is false
{{/value}}
```

Comment: Great job on showing how to to if true, and doing false as well!

Comment: This answer was actually better for me than the accepted one, as I wanted to use this in "automation for jira" plugin which uses mustache.

Comment: This is THE answer guys

Comment: Just to clarify, we can't add anything else in the conditions other than true or false checks as shown above.

Answer (score 36):

In general, you use the `#` syntax:

```
{{#a_boolean}}
  I only show up if the boolean was true.
{{/a_boolean}}
```

The goal is to move as much logic as possible out of the template (which makes sense).

Answer (score 22):

I have a simple and generic hack to perform key/value if statement instead of boolean-only in mustache (and in an extremely readable fashion!) :

```
function buildOptions (object) {
    var validTypes = ['string', 'number', 'boolean'];
    var value;
    var key;
    for (key in object) {
        value = object[key];
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && validTypes.indexOf(typeof value) !== -1) {
            object[key + '=' + value] = true;
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

With this hack, an object like this:

```
var contact = {
  "id": 1364,
  "author_name": "Mr Nobody",
  "notified_type": "friendship",
  "action": "create"
};
```

Will look like this before transformation:

```
var contact = {
  "id": 1364,
  "id=1364": true,
  "author_name": "Mr Nobody",
  "author_name=Mr Nobody": true,
  "notified_type": "friendship",
  "notified_type=friendship": true,
  "action": "create",
  "action=create": true
};
```

And your mustache template will look like this:

```
{{#notified_type=friendship}}
    friendship…
{{/notified_type=friendship}}

{{#notified_type=invite}}
    invite…
{{/notified_type=invite}}
```

Comment: this bloats the mustache data, but is a usable and readable approach worth considering

Comment: The equality example is really useful!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @françois-dispaux solution, I wrote a recursive variant called `prepMustache` browsing multi-level objects and adding `key=value` keys for all child but also :

- `hasTimexxx` for variable timexxx greater than 00:00:00
- `var123>0` for Integer variable var123 is greater than 0
- `key[i]=value` for sub-arrays

And I also put this function in global scope to use it everywhere in my Node-Red project.

```
const prepMustache = (function (object) {

    for (const key in object) {

        const value       = object[key];
        const keyWithVal  = `${key}=${value}`;

        // IS STRING, INT or BOOL
        if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean') {
            
            object[keyWithVal] = true;

            // INT greater than zero
            if (typeof value === 'number' && Number.isInteger(value) && value > 0) {
                const intKeyWithValue = `${key}>0`;
                object[intKeyWithValue] = true;
            }

            // TIME (format 00:00:00) greater than 00:00:00
            else if (typeof value === 'string' && /^([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}$/.test(value)) {
                const timeArray = value.split(':');
                const hours = parseInt(timeArray[0]);
                const minutes = parseInt(timeArray[1]);
                const seconds = parseInt(timeArray[2]);
                if (hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds > 0) {
                    const timeKey = `has${key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}: true`;
                    object[timeKey] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // IS SUB-ARRAY
        else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach((val, i) => {
                if (typeof val === 'object') {
                    prepMustache(val);
                } else {
                    const arrKeyWithVal = `${key}[${i}]=${val}`;
                    object[arrKeyWithVal] = true;
                }
            });
        }

        // IS SUB-OBJECT
        else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            prepMustache(value);
        }
    }

    return object;
});

// Add this for NodeRed global scope only
global.set('prepMustache', prepMustache);
```

use :

```
vars = prepMustache(vars);
```

use (Node-Red) :

```
msg.payload = global.get('prepMustache')(msg.payload)
```