# Kohana - using kostache with handlebars

Tags: php, kohana, kostache

I am using kostache module in KO 3.2 - view classes, templates, everything is based on php. Is this ok, or even recommended, to install handlebars.js? Will this work properly with kostache?

I would do this straight away if it wouldnt be written in javascript though - I'm not sure how will this work, what about people who view my website without js turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a JS templating solution then http://handlebarsjs.com/ is a fine solution. There's no reason why this should not work with [kostache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache).

I'm not sure I understand your second paragraph there. It's a JS templating solution, so it's written in JS. If the user has JS disabled in their browser then the templates will not work, but then neither would the JS that's generating them in the first place.

**Edited:**
It sounds to me like you may be slightly confused here too. Kostache is a server side templating engine that saves you embedding PHP logic in your views. handlerbars.js is a client-side templating engine, saving you from doing DOM manipulation to update content.

Comment: I'm looking for the ability to use {{if}}{{else}} structures, better semantics, and functionalities - handlebars seems to fit this description. But all of these could be done in PHP, that's why I'm not sure about JS solution.

Comment: Although an `if` is not strictly available as it provides [Logic-less templates](http://mustache.github.com/), you are able to process this logic server-side and handle it on the template level as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548943/how-to-handle-an-if-statement-in-a-mustache-template). Alternatively, you're free to import Mustache templates into Handlebars.