# How do I accomplish an if/else using comparison in mustache.js?

Tags: jquery, mustache

I read how to use if/else in mustache.js in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js).

Now my question, it is possible to use in `if` statement the comparison operators ?

like (just I gave a wrong example):

```
{{#ItemIndex==0}}
   <td>{{ItemIndex}}</td>
{{/ItemIndex}}
{{^ItemIndex==0}}
   <td>{{ItemIndex}} *</td>
{{/ItemIndex}}
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that using Mustache.

However, since you're interested in the value that equals 0 (falsy), you can do this:

```
/*
Template:
{{#objs}}
    {{^ItemIndex}}
        {{ItemIndex}}*
    {{/ItemIndex}}
    {{#ItemIndex}}
        {{ItemIndex}}
    {{/ItemIndex}}
{{/objs}}"
*/

var template = "{{#objs}}{{^ItemIndex}}{{ItemIndex}}*{{/ItemIndex}}{{#ItemIndex}}{{ItemIndex}}{{/ItemIndex}}\n\n{{/objs}}"

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent = (Mustache.render(template, {objs: [
    {
        ItemIndex: 0
    }, 
    {
        ItemIndex: 1
    },    
    {
        ItemIndex: 2
    } 
]}))

// result => 0* 1 2
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDKsH/1/)

If you *need* if/else constructs in your templates and like the Mustache syntax, you should check out [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Yes, I saw that is less-logic template. So I will use anyway jquery tmpl.