# Load part of mustache template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I started using mustache and want to know how to load different parts of a template. Like this.

```
require(['jquery','stache!templates/message'], function($, template) {
 'use strict';

var person1 = {
    firstName: "John",     
};
$('#container1').html(template(person1))

var person2 = {
    lastName: "Petersen",       
};
$('#container2').html(template(person2))

});
```

And the html template message.html.

This should only loaded in container1

```
<h1>{{firstName}}</h1>
```

This should only loaded in container2

```
<h1>{{lastName}}<h2>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post the full template in message.html?

Comment: The full template is those two lines with first and last name.

Comment: So it should be two separate templates. Template can be applied only  as whole in mustache.

Comment: Yup impossible. Must be separate templates. If you need conditional inclusion of parts of the template I believe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js) is interesting.