# How do I do an if with value in mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mustache

I have the following code:

```
    <script id="tplPLDSemanal" type="text/template">
       {{#.}}
          <tr>  
              <td width="20%">{{Peso}}</td>                                                                                                                             
              <td width="20%">{{SECO}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Sul}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Nordeste}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Norte}}</td>
          </tr>
       {{/.}}
   </script>
```

and I would like to do something like the following, but it does not work

```
if ({{Peso}} == 2) 
   <td width="20%">Leve</td>
else if({{Peso}} == 4)
        <td width="20%">Media</td>
     else
        <td width="20%">Pesado</td>
```

anyone could help me?

Comment: Aren't Mustache templates supposed to be logic-less?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js)

Comment: @Juhana that question is related, but it deals with binary if/else (the input already is either `true` or `false`), which is different from what's being asked here.

Comment: Mustache templates are by design logic-less, so you have to evaluate those checks before sending the params to the template compiler. Alternatively use [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for Mustache-style templates with logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache allows you to use functions inside the template, you can add a function to your data and add the logic you want inside the template.

Consider the following template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
       {{#.}}
          <tr>
              <td width="20%">{{checkPeso}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{SECO}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Sul}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Nordeste}}</td>
              <td width="20%">{{Norte}}</td>
          </tr>
       {{/.}}
   </script>
<table id="target"></table>
```

The first variable is `checkPeso` which is the name of the function we will add to our data.

Consider the following data:

```
var data = [];
data.push({'SECO': 'val1a', 'Sul': 'val1b', 'Nordeste': 'val1c', 'Norte': 'val1d', 'peso': 0});
data.push({'SECO': 'val2a', 'Sul': 'val2b', 'Nordeste': 'val2c', 'Norte': 'val2d', 'peso': 2});
data.push({'SECO': 'val3a', 'Sul': 'val3b', 'Nordeste': 'val3c', 'Norte': 'val3d', 'peso': 4});
```

You simply add the function to the `data` object with the name `checkPeso`. Inside the function you have access to the data that is being rendered and you can access the data via `this`.

```
data.checkPeso = function () {
    if (this.peso === 2) return 'Leve';
    if (this.peso === 4) return 'Media';

    return 'Pesado';
};
```

Then, you render as usual your Mustache template:

```
var template = $('#template').html();
Mustache.parse(template); // optional, speeds up future uses
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
$('#target').html(rendered);
```

See full demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/90fbq9r5/)

Note: As it is correctly stated, Mustache is logic-less but it allows you to use functions and so you can add logic in your template.