# how to: mustache if else statement

Tags: mustache

How do we write the following in mustache?

I want to check if a variable exists, if it does, I want to check if that variable equals another variable. so

This would be the PHP equivalent

```
if ($example && $example == $type) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively mustache shortcodes use the # symbol for 'if' so assuming your shortcode is {{example}} then

```
{{#example}} 
    Start condition if example exists
{{/example}}
```

And ^ works the same way for 'if does not exist'

```
{{ ^example}}
    Start condition if example does not exist
{{/example}}
```

NOTE - If using mustache conditions you must must remember to close the condition the same way you would an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mustache the goal is to perform this type of logic in the controller, and not in the template. As per [How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js) You would want to do this type of check in the controller and generate a boolean that you can use the in the template

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a closure to the mustache data and put this logic into that closure, something like:

```
var md = {};
md['my_condition'] = function(){
  return (this['some_attr'] && this['some_attr'] == 'expected_val');
}
```

and then use the `md` object as data to the mustache template.