# How to use if-else as mustache grammar?

Tags: vue.js, mustache

[how-to-mustache-if-else-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485653/how-to-mustache-if-else-statement)

After I read this, I tried as the article in Vue.js but it emitted just error.

```
<tr v-for="(data, i) in userList" :key="i">
<td>{{#data.authority==1}}Admin{{/data.authority==1}}</td>
</tr>
```

If I write just `{{data.authority}}` then it worked well.

How to use if-else as mustache grammar in Vue.js?

Comment: What error occurred?

Comment: Errors compiling template:

 `invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    _s(#data.authority==1)+"Admin"+_s(/data.authority==1)

  Raw expression: {{#data.authority==1}}Admin{{/data.authority==1}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue uses interpolation with mustache syntax that works different from the post you've shared. Anything you write in *{{}}* gets evaluated by JavaScript.

So, you can write any kind of expression:

```js
{{ 2 + 2 }} // output will be 4
{{ 'Hell World' }} // output: 'Hello World'
```

So, in your situation, you can write a ternary operator:

```js
<tr v-for="(data, i) in userList" :key="i">
  <td>{{ data.authority === 1 ? 'Admin' : 'Not Admin' }}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to only show a `td` element when `user.authority === 1` you should use v-if or v-show instead.

You can use expressions and not statements inside {{}}. So a plain if/else would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Like vanilla js inside mustache:
`{{ data.auth ? 'user' : 'guest'}}`