# how to use ternary operator in mustache template

Tags: node.js, mustache

I have a scenario where I am getting `{{isdone}}` value with Boolean data.

I want to be printed as "pending" for `false` value and "Done" for `true`.

I'm using below code, Which isn't working.

```
{{isdone}} == false ? "pending" : "Done"
```

Comment: are you doing it in anuglar or something else?

Comment: Mustache templates are said to be "logic-less", though you can have `if/else` statements in them (See this question for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js). I highly doubt a ternary operator is possible in a template.

Comment: Thanks @Seblor , Mean while I googled and found the same,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have control of your context data, correct way is to pass another variable, that will already contain `pending` or `Done` beforehand.

If you don't have control over the data, then maybe moustache isn't good for you as you may need template engine that can have some more logic in it to transform data a bit.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the `^` block for else.

You can (now) use the `^` block for an `else` or `false` condition. Something like this should work:

```js
{{#isdone}}Done{{/isdone}}{{^isdone}}pending{{/isdone}}
```

Or as a more readable multi-line block of code:

```js
{{#isdone}}
Done
{{/isdone}}
{{^isdone}}
pending
{{/isdone}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to register a `ternary` helper for that

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ternary", function (condition, trueValue, falseValue, options) {
   return condition ? trueValue : falseValue;
});
```

and then in your templates use it like

```
{{ternary isdone "Done" "pending"}}
```